Can I pass as callback to Watson Speech-to-text when I start the stream?
I am trying to get transcripts from Watson Speech-to-Text.  I am initiating a wss:// web socket connection from the telephony service I am using.  However I don't have programatic control of the client (which is the telephony service).  All I can do is tell it a URL to open and redirect the stream.  So I would like to register a callback at the time I am opening up the stream which will then deliver the transcript to my app server.
